# Can Helm/mu4e learn which selection/contacts I use most often?

Tags: helm, spacemacs, mu4e

I'm using *org-contacts* as mu4e address book.  When I start typing an address in, say, the *To:* field and press `TAB`, I get a *Helm* buffer with possible completions, ordered alphabetically.

Is there any way I can make mu4e/Helm **learn** which addresses I use most often and order the matches by usage frequency?

Comment: Package `helm-adaptive` does this, but it is not well maintained.

I haven't tried it, but see [this](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1228#issuecomment-149030920 "Github comment") .

You'd  have to find the name of the helm source responsible for org contacts and add it to the list. 

I did a lot of googling but couldn't find out myself what its name was. You might be able to find it by doing `SPC h d v` (`describe-variable`), typing `helm-source-`, then searching among the results. - Comment from [kbdluv](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/18016/kbdluv)